# I received connection refused error while trying to stream live video through RTMP with FFMPEG

Tags: node.js, apache, websocket, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am working on a nodeJs app that can send camera stream to third party plartform i.e Facebook and Youtube using the RTMP protoco;.. It works well on my localhost but once i deploy to the server, it only give me errors. The error I get is below on this content..
Here is my codes

server.js

```js
const child_process = require('child_process'); // To be used later for running FFmpeg
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Listening...');
});

// Serve static files out of the www directory, where we will put our HTML page
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));


const wss = new WebSocketServer({
  server: server
});
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  
  
  
  const rtmpUrl = 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MyStreamId';
  console.log('Target RTMP URL:', rtmpUrl);
  
  // Launch FFmpeg to handle all appropriate transcoding, muxing, and RTMP.
  // If 'ffmpeg' isn't in your path, specify the full path to the ffmpeg binary.
  const ffmpeg = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', [
    // Facebook requires an audio track, so we create a silent one here.
    // Remove this line, as well as `-shortest`, if you send audio from the browser.
    //'-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'anullsrc',
    
    // FFmpeg will read input video from STDIN
    '-i', '-',
    
    // Because we're using a generated audio source which never ends,
    // specify that we'll stop at end of other input.  Remove this line if you
    // send audio from the browser.
    //'-shortest',
    
    // If we're encoding H.264 in-browser, we can set the video codec to 'copy'
    // so that we don't waste any CPU and quality with unnecessary transcoding.
    // If the browser doesn't support H.264, set the video codec to 'libx264'
    // or similar to transcode it to H.264 here on the server.
    '-vcodec', 'copy',
    
    // AAC audio is required for Facebook Live.  No browser currently supports
    // encoding AAC, so we must transcode the audio to AAC here on the server.
    '-acodec', 'aac',
    
    // FLV is the container format used in conjunction with RTMP
    '-f', 'flv',
    
    // The output RTMP URL.
    // For debugging, you could set this to a filename like 'test.flv', and play
    // the resulting file with VLC.  Please also read the security considerations
    // later on in this tutorial.
    rtmpUrl 
  ]);
  
  // If FFmpeg stops for any reason, close the WebSocket connection.
  ffmpeg.on('close', (code, signal) => {
    console.log('FFmpeg child process closed, code ' + code + ', signal ' + signal);
    ws.terminate();
  });
  
  // Handle STDIN pipe errors by logging to the console.
  // These errors most commonly occur when FFmpeg closes and there is still
  // data to write.  If left unhandled, the server will crash.
  ffmpeg.stdin.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('FFmpeg STDIN Error', e);
  });
  
  // FFmpeg outputs all of its messages to STDERR.  Let's log them to the console.
  ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('FFmpeg STDERR:', data.toString());
  });

  // When data comes in from the WebSocket, write it to FFmpeg's STDIN.
  ws.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('DATA', msg);
    ffmpeg.stdin.write(msg);
  });
  
  // If the client disconnects, stop FFmpeg.
  ws.on('close', (e) => {
    ffmpeg.kill('SIGINT');
  });
  
});
```

On the server.js file i create a websocket to receive stream data from the client side and then use FFMPEG to send the stream data over to youtube via the RTMP url

Here is my client.js code

```js
const ws = new WebSocket(
             'wss://my-websocket-server.com'

        );
         ws.addEventListener('open', (e) => {
             console.log('WebSocket Open', e);
             drawVideosToCanvas();
             mediaStream = getMixedVideoStream(); // 30 FPS
             mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
               mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264',
               //videoBitsPerSecond : 3000000000
               bitsPerSecond: 6000000
             });

             mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e) => {
               ws.send(e.data);
             });
             mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
              ws.close.bind(ws);
              isRecording = false;
              actionBtn.textContent = 'Start Streaming';
              actionBtn.onclick = startRecording;
             }
             mediaRecorder.onstart = function() {
              isRecording = true;
              actionBtn.textContent = 'Stop Streaming';
              actionBtn.onclick = stopRecording;
              screenShareBtn.onclick = startSharing;
              screenShareBtn.disabled = false;
             }
             //mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', ws.close.bind(ws));

             mediaRecorder.start(1000); // Start recording, and dump data every second

           });
```

On my client.js file, i captured users camera and then open the websocket server to send the data to the server.. Every thing works fine on local host expect for when i deploy it to live server..
i am wondering if there is a bad configuration on the server.. The server is Centos 7.8 and the app was runing on Apache software
Here is how i configured the virtual host for the websocket domain

```js
ServerName my-websocket.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
  RewriteRule .* "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/$1" [P,L]

  ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1"
  ProxyRequests off
```

I don't know much about server configuration but i just thought may be the configuration has to do with why FFMPEg can not open connection to RTMP protocol on the server.

here is the error am getting

```js
FFmpeg STDERR: Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration:
FFmpeg STDERR: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s

DATA <Buffer 1a>
DATA <Buffer 45 df a3 a3 42 86 81 01 42 f7 81 01 42 f2 81 04 42 f3 81 08 42 82 88 6d 61 74 72 6f 73 6b 61 42 87 81 0442 85 81 02 18 53 80 67 01 ff ff ff ff ff ff ... 53991 more bytes>
DATA <Buffer 40 c1 81 00 f0 80 7b 83 3e 3b 07 d6 4e 1c 11 b4 7f cb 5e 68 9b d5 2a e3 06 c6 f3 94 ff 29 16 b2 ff 60 04ac 37 fb 1a 15 ea 40 29 39 a0 1a cd 02 b8 e3 ... 56206 more bytes>
FFmpeg STDERR: Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         :
FFmpeg STDERR: Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #1:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1366x768, SAR 1:1 DAR 683:384, 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc (default)

FFmpeg STDERR: [tcp @ 0xe5fac0] Connection to tcp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
[rtmp @ 0xe0fb80] Cannot open connection tcp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935

FFmpeg STDERR: rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/mystreamid: Network is unreachable

FFmpeg child process closed, code 1, signal null
```

I will really appreciate if I could get some insight on what may be causing this issue or what i can do to solve it..Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't think webm muxer works with RTMP